# How to get the substring of a string that contains HTML tags using C# .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring, html

I have a substring what contains HTML tag and I need to shorten it but display it with the same formatting as it appears on the string.

It doesn't have to be exactly X characters long, but it should be short enough to be displayed inside a panel with a certain  width and height?

Is there any way I can achieve this using c#?

What about using CSS? I.e. displaying the panel with a fixed height regardless of its content?

Thanks..

Example: I have the following panel containing a label that contains text with html tags:

[image: Example]

I need to remove the scroll bar without making the panel longer but keeping this height & this width..

Comment: You mean turn "<span>Some Really Long String</span" into "<span> Some Rea...</span>?

Comment: Yes, this is one option, another is by displaying **Some Really Bold String** into **Some Rea** because that's the dimention of the Panel.(I want to avoid scrollbars and still keep the panel's dimentions by displaying only part of its content)

Comment: I edited the post adding the example.

Comment: use css: `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Are you trying to strip HTML ?

Comment: can you post it as an answer so i can mark it?

Comment: endri, you need to include the poster's name in your comment so they are informed of the comment. like this: @PrasadJadhav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have following html code:

```
<div class="div1"> Some Really Bold String </div>
```

You can provide css to hide the scroll bars,

```
.div { overflow:hidden; height:200px; width:200px;}
```

`height` and `width` values are just for example purpose.
`overflow:hidden` does not let the content of the div to expand out side the div.
you will find more information on `overflow` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to find the contents of the specific tag. Use a .substring to shorten the result afterwards.

A example could be:

```
<h1>head</h1>
<p>contents</p>
```

Regex could be:

```
<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)</p>
```

Result would be:

```
<p>contents</p>
```

Now just exclude the start and end tag. as its a fixed length.

I found more interesting reading about changing the content between HTML tags. Take a read here (regex ftw!):

http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/how-to-match-and-replace-content-between-two-html-tags-using-regular-expressions

---

Another solution that might not drive you as crazy if you want to solve it in c#:

[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

Take a look at the examples part of the site. Great little tool!

Comment: HTML with Regex again?? Have a look at the masterpiece here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1090657.

Comment: Really really cool post - love what he did. That being said, i have had a boss that made a living parsing html with regex. Regex finds patterns. Any string can have those patterns. While i agree the CSS solution might be the more sensible, regex is far from impossible. Everyone seemed to pursue the CSS solution, so i tried to think of a solution that could be plausible in c#.

Comment: Thanks @Wraithbone really interesting